# How to access USB device data using pyusb?

Tags: python-3.x, usb, sensors, pyusb

I am trying to stream data from a USB sensor-type device. I have tried the following code:

```
import usb.core
device = usb.find(idVendor=0x1234, idProduct=0x4321)
print(device.read(0x81, 7))
```

The output I get is:

```
array('B', [1, 96])
```

I'm really unsure how to use this and get meaningful sensor data. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

For info, here's the output I get when I run `print(device)`:

```
DEVICE ID 1234:4321 on Bus 001 Address 013 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :    0x8 (8 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x0403
 idProduct              : 0xc2b0
 bcdDevice              : 0x1000 Device 16.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 XXXXXXXXXXXX
 iProduct               :    0x2 XXXX
 iSerialNumber          :    0x0 
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 500 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x20 (32 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0x80 Bus Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xfa (500 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Vendor Specific ===========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :   0xff Vendor Specific
     bInterfaceSubClass :   0xff
     bInterfaceProtocol :   0xff
     iInterface         :    0x2 XXXX
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x2: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x2 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
```

Comment: There is no general USB sensor protocol. The sensor most likely implements a custom protocol. So you will need to find documentation about the protocol. With the given information in the question, it impossible to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added more info but I'm unsure how useful this is.

Comment: It doesn't help much. It just shows that the sensor has an in and out bulk point in addition to the mandatory control endpoint. And it confirms that it doesn't implement any of the USB classes (such as mass storage or CDC).

Comment: Ok so you'd expect there to be a manufacturing protocol somewhere to reference for access?

Comment: Nearly no device has a public USB protocol. So you usually have to play detective and reverse engineer the protocol yourself by looking at how the device communication works with the manufacturers driver, using e.g. Wireshark.

Comment: Ok that's been handy for me. What information do I need from the manufacturers protocol and how might I use this to pull data from the device? I suppose I'm pretty unsure what Python code snippet example I might be able to use to get me started beyond what I posted in my initial question. Any ideas?